# Why this sed is not working?

Tags: sed

I want to massively change some css references in more than 200 html files. Most of the files are static HTML generated automatically. 
Now, I need to change the location of some css files. 
So, I used that sed:

```
sed -s 's/href="*_css/href="css/g' ./12*.htm*
```

The source is like that:

```
href="11.2.Lab%20_css/styles.css"
href="10.2.Lab%20_css/styles.css"
```

But running the sed, nothing happen!

Where is the error?

Answer (score 2):

It's confusing, but `*` matches an arbitrary string in `bash`, whereas in regular expressions `*` repeats the previous pattern an arbitrary number of times.

So you need `.*` instead of `*` (match any character any number of times); your string specifies an arbitrary number of double-quotes followed by underscore.

Note that the dots in the source strings are unrelated to the `.` in the regular expression, which matches any character, including itself.